# I just want my form to be key with a specific answer by my customer , how to?

Tags: javascript

I do not want to used captacha on my site. as such i would just like my customer to key a specific answer in the form that i have created.

For example = What is 3 + 4 ? and i only want the field to be key with number 7. for instance if my customer keyed any other number then 7, the form would not be submitted and would request for the right answer.

I'm trying to use spry widget to perform this trick but have failed multiple times even after changing the html code.

here's the code:

```html
<span id="sprytextfield4">
      <input type="text" name="huamn" id="huamn" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">
          Please provide an answer
      </span>
</span>
```

```js
var sprytextfield4 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield4", "text", {minValue:7, maxValue:7, maxChars:1});
```

Comment: Note that client-side validation, i.e. checking a field value in the browser, is not equivalent to a CAPTCHA which is validated on the server-side. You're going about this the wrong way.

Comment: I recommend you strongly not to use JavaScript captcha as it will entirely remove the point of a captcha, which is to be validated on the server side.

Comment: @NabeelSheikh javascript captcha works just fine when it's accompanied with serverside validation.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell while true, the user has given no indications that they understand that idea.

Comment: @user2876584 can you please also show the code you use on the server to validate the answer after it leaves your user's browser by the form being submitted?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Asker said that the form shouldn't be submitted if the answer is wrong. That means JS validation instead of server-side.

Comment: @Oriol yup, I would do the EXACT same thing. If the field is wrong, don't submit... if the submit still happens, you validate AGAIN on the server.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell But if you validate it client-side, a bot could look your JS code and find the correct answer! Then, the captcha isn't secure

Comment: @oriol there are all kids of "if's" but the bottom line is, for 99% of the website out there, the bot's aren't programmed to dig into corner cases... they try a submit and move on.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell WHAT??? So you program insecure codes because *the bot's aren't programmed to dig into corner cases*??? AYFKM?  If you hope that bots won't attack your site, don't use captcha. But captcha is used to test if the client is a human being, so don't use broken captchas!!

Comment: @oriol who said anything about insecure? I actually code fairly solid code... and if (in the slight change) that a bot is intentionally going after a site I create, I strengthen the CAPTCHA. It's modular and easy to swap out. I'd rather focus on usability over obscure image CAPTCHAs that's a HUGE PAIN IN THE ASS for anyone who's ever tried and failed on those obfuscated texts that are OVERKILL for the majority of websites out there.

Comment: @oriol how many captcha's have you entered here on StackOverflow? If you had to enter one of those ridiculous image captchas every time you wanted to post a question/answer/comment, how often would you use this site? There are better ways to prove a "human", and it's not that hard to thwart a bot.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell That's the point. Captchas bother human beings, so you can: decide not to use captchas, and hope bots won't attack you; or use secure captchas; or a mix. But if you sometimes/always use captchas, at least make them secure, because human beings will be bothered the same whether it is secure or not.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validate using javascript on the client, here's a quick and dirty way that I've used.

***note: you still need to validate the same question on the server to ensure the spammer hasn't circumvented by disabling Javascript***

jQuery

```
$('#submit').click(function (event) {
    var color = $('#color').val().toLowerCase();
    if (color != 'orange') {
        alert('incorrect');
    } else {
        alert('yay!');
        // submit the form
        // BUT DON'T FORGET TO VALIDATE input.color AGAIN ON THE SERVER.
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g4Gu8/1/

if your site is of low importance to spammers... IE: not StackOverflow or Redit, you can typically get away with this type of validation and pretty much avoid getting spam. If your site becomes a direct target for attack, and bots are written to circumvent this very low level of protection, you should look into using one of the many pre-build captcha libraries out there and implement both the server side and client side validation. I for one can't stand image CAPTCHA's, so I prefer a method of "human verification" that is less intrusive.

Comment: And now, a bot only has to use `.innerHTML` of the `<script>` tag and find `orange`.

Comment: for 99% of the website out there, the bot's aren't programmed to dig into corner cases... they try a submit and move on.

Comment: if you need stronger security because you actually have something important on the internet, you can use one of the dozens of prebuilt CAPTCHA's out there, and incorporate the supplied server side validation process. This isn't a wheel that needs to be reinvented.

Comment: If you hope that bots won't attack your site, don't use captcha. But captcha is used to test if the client is a human being, so don't use broken captchas!! Read [How not to implement CAPTCHAs](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/08/how-not-to-implement-captchas.html), especially "**CAPTCHA solution must not be stored on the client**"